# TableView in a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to put a tableview into a tableview cell. I like the formatted look it gives. I'm hoping to put in a few fields, for like name, email, etc. What am I missing to be able to make this work? Currently I can not set "ProfileCell" as the tableview class.

In my .h file of the profile cell I added:

```
@interface ProfileCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

and in my .m file I added some basic methods for the tableview:

```
#import "ProfileCell.h"

@implementation ProfileCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the specified section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Doing this");
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have seperated the code for the cellview tableview into it's own files, and linked tableview to this class, however it does not fire when viewed:

```
@interface ProfileBasicDetails : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

**Per comments below**

This is what my page should look like when said and done. It's so users can enter in their details, while looking nice and formatted, but not ghetto looking.

[image]

Comment: There is a well hidden warning in the docs: *You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.* As table views subclass UIScrollView, this applies here at well: Don't do it. It works or might not: it is unexpected behavior. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-DontLinkElementID_5

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if that still counts even if it's locked? I'm not looking to scroll that one, just have it format out the items for input like you see in other apps.

Comment: You would need access to the source code to answer this question. And I don't have that.

Comment: Why actually do u think you have to place a tableview in a cell. I just see a tableview with a tableviews header, a section with 2 cells and a tableview footer.

Comment: Look at the 2nd image down: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HFuIX.png

Based on some of the other apps I have looked at, it looks like this is what they are using to create that format/design in the app.. let me see if I can find an example for you.

Comment: Again: I don't see a table view on a cell.

Comment: That's what it is, but thank, you gave me an idea on how I can get similar looking results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've embedded the UITableView into the cell?

You should wire the tableview to an outlet in the cell. Then set the delegate on the tableview in your awakeFromNib method.

*As vikingosegundo mentioned in the comments, this is potentially a pretty fragile approach.

Comment: There is a well hidden warning in the docs: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled. As table views subclass UIScrollView, this applies here at well: Don't do it. It works or might not: it is unexpected behavior. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-DontLinkElementID_5

Comment: Agreed, some care would need to be made.  Disabling scrolling on that view, probably disabling User Interaction as well.  (Taps on the embedded tableview won't be passed to the parent tableview, etc)

If you were determined to do it this way, this is how it could be done.

Comment: You would only assume that it will work, you don't have any guarantee that it won't break at any time.

Comment: And i just point out: this answer deals with undefined behavior.

Comment: I uploaded a new image at the bottom of the post. If you would not use a tableview in the cell to produce that type of view within a cell, what would you recommend?

Comment: I would just lay it out with labels, text fields, and 1pt heigh views (for the separators)